# Loading XML with AJAX but it is not showing  results

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I am loading an XML file then I will display the contents of it depending on their tag, but it seems my Code is not working. Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xml> 
<word> 
  <threeletter>RIP</threeletter> 
  <fourletter>PIER</fourletter>
  <fiveletter>SPIRE</fiveletter> 
  <sixletter>SPIDER</sixletter> 
 </word>
</xml>
```

Here is my Ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
    url: "dictionary.xml", 
    success: function( xml ) { 
        $(xml).find("sixletter").each(function(){ 
            $("ul").append( 
              "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>"); 
        }); 
    } 
});
})
```

Both of them are in the same folder.

Comment: try adding the correct dataType and that the call is a GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, using jQuery 1.7.1

Perhaps you don't have universal read access on the xml file?  Navigate your browser to your xml file, if it doesn't load, there's your problem.

Comment: +1 - Additionally, an `error: function(x) { }` section could be added to trap and debug the return message(s)

Comment: How would I navigate my browser to my xml file?  I am using google chrome, and I have the latest jquery, I just downloaded last week

Comment: Just type in the url into the address bar.  You said the the 2 files are in the same location, so replace the last part of the URL with dictionary.xml

Comment: I've tried it on Chrome it is not working but in firefox it is working

Comment: Infact, it's just occurred that you said "Both of them are in the same folder" ... both of what? is the JS you pasted from your html file? or from an included JS file?  The xml file will need to be relative to the html file where it is run.

Comment: The XML file is in the same file path with the JS Codes.

Comment: @user962206 - that is your problem then. you need to change `url: "dictionary.xml"` to `url: "jsFolderPathForCodes/dictionary.xml"`

Comment: OKay it is now finally working but! it kept showing the "SPIDER" 2 times in the LI

Comment: I actually don't know, perhaps if (as the asker) you upvote it?

Comment: No, hit the "tick" to accept @DavidDownes' answer - and upvote it as well, as I did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dataType:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
    url: "dictionary.xml", 
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function( xml ) { 
        $(xml).find("sixletter").each(function(){ 
            $("ul").append( 
              "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>"); 
        }); 
    } 
});
})
```

Hope it helps